# groovy with ambiguous closure: How to resolve

Tags: groovy

I am trying to do this in groovy

```
def results = new File(someDirectory).listFiles { it.name.startsWith 'foo'}
```

But, I get and understandable error:

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method java.io.File#listFiles.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [class change$_getRollback_closure1] due to overlapping prototypes between:
    [interface java.io.FileFilter]
    [interface java.io.FilenameFilter]
```

how do I tell it *use the one with FileFilter*?

I ended up writing it plain-old java style:

```
File[] files = someDir.listFiles( new FileFilter(){
    @Override
    boolean accept(File pathname) {
        return pathname.name.startsWith("foo")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can cast or coerce the closure to specify which SAM-type/functional interface you mean.

```
// using a typecast:
def results = new File(someDirectory).listFiles((FileFilter) { it.name.startsWith 'foo'})

// using as keyword:
def results = new File(someDirectory).listFiles({ it.name.startsWith 'foo'} as FileFilter)

// using SAM-type coercion:
FileFilter ff = { it.name.startsWith 'foo'}
def results = new File(someDirectory).listFiles(ff)
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for